# Whats the Max number of tasks can be created in dispatch_async in an ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, multitasking, dispatch-async

Whats the Max number of tasks can be created with dispatch_async in the following scenario in an ios multitasking app

```
for(i=0 ; i<=? ; i++)
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// some code 

 });
}
```

is there any limit for i here ?  any suggestions would be appreciated! thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no hard limit.  There are, however, performance implications.  If you dispatch too many tasks at once your app might start to lag.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit. You might run out of memory like in any other code.